# Tesseract erroneously detects text as vertical

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I try to read numbers from scanned documents with Tesseract. I encountered the following problem: In a row of numbers like

```
3.456,78
3.564,98
3.612,34
```

Tesseract recognizes three vertical lines

```
 .456,78
 .564,98
 .612,34
```

and a horizontal line

```
 www
```

Thus, it erroneously interpreted the three "3"s in a row as a horizontal "www" (textangle 90).

The text is in monospace and the distance between the dot and the adjacent digits is comparatively large.

I already tried to switch off vertical text recognition by setting the control parameter "textord_tabfind_force_vertical_text" to 0, but Tesseract seems to ignore it. My hope was when vertical text recognition is disabled, Tesseract no longer identifies the "3"s as turned "w"s.

I use Tesseract 4.0.0 with psm=12 and oem=1.

Any help is greatly appreciated!